# What are the dimensions of LEGO 10221 Super Star Destroyer?

Tags: sets, star-wars, size

What is the length, width, and height of the 10221 Super Star Destroyer set, fully built, including its stand?

I'm trying to make a display case for one.

Answer (score 5):

So the box says 49 inches long, the official description says "under 50 inches long".
I just measured the width (about 13.25 inches) and height (about 9.5 inches) on my assembled set.

So a rough minimum inner size box would be 50"L x 13.5"W x 10"H.

Comment: Or, in a little more common units: box should be about 127 x 35.3 x 25.4 cm.

Answer (score 1):

4ft 2in long
14in wide
10 in tall with stand

Answer (score 0):

52in. W x 14in. D x 14in. H is the size of the display case you will need.  Don't try to buy one, I'm looking for one, and the cheapest I can find cost $499.